# how to select all duplicates efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select all rows that have a value that already exists in the table. I did not find a better solution than

```
select * 
from provisioning_requests tt 
where code in (select code 
               from provisioning_requests tt2 
               where tt2.id <> tt.id)
```

This seems a bit naive. Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the duplicate rows or you want to see only duplicated rows?

Comment: I want to see the duplicated rows.

Comment: @nathanvda: I just wonder why your original method isn't good. Can you please explain?

Comment: Well to me it is kind of obvious that the query is very naive and not very efficient. For each code this will query if there are other provisioning-requests, so I was wondering if there were 'smarter' (as in more efficient) ways. And there were :) HTH.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
select * 
from provisioning_requests t1
 join (select code from provisioning_requests group by code having count(*)>1) t2
 ON t1.code = t2.code
```

OR

```
select * 
from provisioning_requests
 WHERE code in (select code from provisioning_requests group by code having count(*)>1)
```

Comment: This finds me the codes, so I would write: `select * from ag6.provisioning_requests where code in
(
select code
from ag6.provisioning_requests
group by code
having count(*)>1
)` and it is indeed a lot quicker. Thanks.

Comment: The first one is the best if you are looking for human readability also.  It groups the duplicates together.  It has the slight downside of adding the "code" field value to the end of each entry returned.

Comment: @ermSO You could just `select t1.*` instead of `*`

Answer (score 10):

An Auto join do the job

```
select tt.* 
from provisioning_requests tt 
    INNER JOIN provisioning_requests tt2 
        ON tt.code = tt2.code
        AND tt2.id <> tt.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.*
from(
    select *, count(1) over(partition by code) as cnt
    from test
) as t
where t.cnt > 1
```

Comment: Wow. I like this one as well. It is slower than @niktrs or @scorpi0 answer, but a very nice addition to my toolbox. I did not know the `over (partition by code)` construct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use operator `exists`, it produces better performance:

```
select * 
from provisioning_requests tt 
where exists
(
    select 1
    from provisioning_requests tt2
    where tt2.id <> tt.id and tt2.code = tt.code
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can monitor the row Codes by

```
select code 
from provisioning_requests tt 
group by code
having count(code) > 1
```

Comment: @niktrs gave the same answer first and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the distinct keyword?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., DISTINCT(code) from provisioning_requests;
```

Comment: I did a bit of research and found out that DISTINCT can be heavier than a sub-query as it will retrieve all the rows, and then eliminate the duplicates. The sub-query method seems to work fine. You may want to read this: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/postgresql/article.php/3437821/SELECT-DISTINCT-A-SQL-Case-Study.htm

Comment: that is indeed correct. Furthermore, I want to find all doubles, not ignore them.

Comment: @nathanvda: That's true. I'm sorry I jumped to answer the question. I missed the point entirely. I think niktrs' answer is a good fit. If you are looking for performance, I believe, joins are costlier than sub-queries.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using self join and also an index over Code column would make it perform better.

```
select pr1.* from provisioning_requests pr1
join provisioning_requests pr2 on pr1.code = pr2.code and pr1.id <> pr2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) FROM provisioning_requests HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: Mmmmm. Not sure what you are counting here.